# Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight 30 1 5 5 0, but got 5-dimensional input of size [4, 2, 1, 256, 256] instead

Tags: python, arrays, pytorch, torch

I have a dataloader as below which load data with a batch size (default to 8):

```py
class DataLoaderStego(DataLoader):
    def __init__(self, cover_dir, stego_dir, embedding_otf=False,
                 shuffle=False, pair_constraint=False, batch_size=1,
                 transform=None, num_workers=0, pin_memory=False):
        self.pair_constraint = pair_constraint
        self.embedding_otf = embedding_otf
        if pair_constraint and batch_size % 2 == 0:
            dataset = DatasetPair(cover_dir, stego_dir, embedding_otf,
                                  transform)
            _batch_size = int(batch_size / 2)
        else:
            dataset = DatasetNoPair(cover_dir, stego_dir, embedding_otf,
                                    transform)
            _batch_size = batch_size
        if pair_constraint:
            if shuffle:
                sampler = RandomSampler(dataset)
            else:
                sampler = SequentialSampler(dataset)
        else:
            sampler = RandomBalancedSampler(dataset)
        super(DataLoaderStego, self). \
            __init__(dataset, _batch_size, None, sampler,
                     None, num_workers, pin_memory=pin_memory, drop_last=True)
        self.shuffle = shuffle

    def __iter__(self):
        return DataLoaderIterWithReshape(self)
        # if self.pair_constraint:
        # return DataLoaderIterWithReshape(self)
        # else:
        #     return DataLoaderIter(self)
```

This class make the dataset using `DatasetPair` class:

```py
class DatasetPair(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, cover_dir, stego_dir, embedding_otf=False,
                 transform=None):
        self.cover_dir = cover_dir
        self.stego_dir = stego_dir
        self.cover_list = [x.split('/')[-1]
                           for x in glob(cover_dir + '/*')]
        self.transform = transform
        self.embedding_otf = embedding_otf
        assert len(self.cover_list) != 0, "cover_dir is empty"
        # stego_list = ['.'.join(x.split('/')[-1].split('.')[:-1])
        #               for x in glob(stego_dir + '/*')]


    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        idx = int(idx)
        labels = np.array([0, 1], dtype='int32')
        cover_path = os.path.join(self.cover_dir,
                                  self.cover_list[idx])
        print("cover path", cover_path)
        # cover = Image.open(cover_path)
        cover = Image.open(cover_path)
        # print("@@@", cover)
        images = np.empty((2, cover.size[0], cover.size[1], 1),
                          dtype='uint8')
        print("images", images.shape) # Print image
        images[0, :, :, 0] = np.array(cover)
        if self.embedding_otf:
            images[1, :, :, 0] = np.copy(images[0, :, :, 0])
            beta_path = os.path.join(self.stego_dir,
                                     '.'.join(self.cover_list[idx].
                                              split('.')[:-1]) + '.mat')
            beta_map = io.loadmat(beta_path)['pChange']
            rand_arr = np.random.rand(cover.size[0], cover.size[1])
            inf_map = rand_arr < (beta_map / 2.)
            images[1, np.logical_and(
                images[0, :, :, 0] != 255, inf_map), 0] += 1
            inf_map[:, :] = rand_arr > 1 - (beta_map / 2.)
            images[1, np.logical_and(
                images[0, :, :, 0] != 0, inf_map), 0] -= 1
        else:
            stego_path = os.path.join(self.stego_dir,
                                      self.cover_list[idx])
            print("stego path", stego_path)
            images[1, :, :, 0] = Image.open(stego_path)
        samples = {'images': images, 'labels': labels}
        print(images[0].shape)
        if self.transform:
            samples = self.transform(samples)
        return samples
```

All of my images are with size of 256*256 when I print `cover`:

```
@@@ <PIL.PpmImagePlugin.PpmImageFile image mode=L size=256x256 at 0x7F96631B8748>
```

When I create my network model with these configurations:

```
class MyNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, with_bn=False, threshold=3):
        super(YeNet, self).__init__()
        self.with_bn = with_bn
        self.preprocessing = SRM_conv2d(1, 0)
        self.TLU = nn.Hardtanh(-threshold, threshold, True)
        ...

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.float()
        print("########", x.shape)
        x = self.preprocessing(x)
        ...
```

And run my network, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 169, in <module>
    train(epoch)
  File "main.py", line 121, in train
    outputs = net(images)
  File "/home/emad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/emad/myworks/stego/codes/analysis/YeNet-Pytorch/YeNet.py", line 110, in forward
    x = self.preprocessing(x)
  File "/home/emad/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/emad/myworks/stego/codes/analysis/YeNet-Pytorch/YeNet.py", line 53, in forward
    self.dilation, self.groups
RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight 30 1 5 5 0, but got 5-dimensional input of size [4, 2, 1, 256, 256] instead
```

This is my network call:

```
for batch_idx, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        images, labels = Variable(
            data['images']), Variable(data['labels'])
        if args.cuda:
            images, labels = images.cuda(), labels.cuda()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(images)
```

And this is `self.preprocessing` function:

```py
class SRM_conv2d(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, stride=1, padding=0):
        super(SRM_conv2d, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = 1
        self.out_channels = 30
        self.kernel_size = (5, 5)
        if isinstance(stride, int):
            self.stride = (stride, stride)
        else:
            self.stride = stride
        if isinstance(padding, int):
            self.padding = (padding, padding)
        else:
            self.padding = padding
        self.dilation = (1, 1)
        self.transpose = False
        self.output_padding = (0,)
        self.groups = 1
        print(1)
        self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(30, 1, 5, 5),
                                requires_grad=True)
        print(2)
        self.bias = Parameter(torch.Tensor(30),
                              requires_grad=True)
        self.reset_parameters()

    def reset_parameters(self):
        self.weight.data.numpy()[:] = SRM_npy
        self.bias.data.zero_()

    def forward(self, input):
        # print(
        #     "3333", input, self.weight, self.bias,
        #     self.stride, self.padding,
        #     self.dilation, self.groups
        # )
        print("###")
        return F.conv2d(
            input, self.weight, self.bias,
            self.stride, self.padding,
            self.dilation, self.groups
        )
        print("$$$")
```

I want to enable batch input for my network. But also when I run my code with `batch_size=1` get the same error.

**Extra info**:
These are my three transforms which I use:

```py
class ToTensor(object):
    def __call__(self, samples):
        images, labels = samples['images'], samples['labels']
        print("EEE", images.shape)
        images = images.transpose((0, 3, 1, 2))
        # images = (images.transpose((0,3,1,2)).astype('float32') / 127.5) - 1.
        return {'images': torch.from_numpy(images),
                'labels': torch.from_numpy(labels).long()}


class RandomRot(object):
    def __call__(self, samples):
        images = samples['images']
        rot = random.randint(0, 3)
        return {'images': np.rot90(images, rot, axes=[1, 2]).copy(),
                'labels': samples['labels']}


class RandomFlip(object):
    def __call__(self, samples):
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            images = samples['images']
            return {'images': np.flip(images, axis=2).copy(),
                    'labels': samples['labels']}
        else:
            return samples
```

Comment: i'm having a hard time following the evolution of your input as it's being transformed but since you seem well versed, why don't you just track the input shape with print statements every time the input is being modified? you'll find the error when the input starts having 5 dimensions rather than 4

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you are loading two images in the dataset object and creating a 4D tensor? A dataset object is generally expected to return a single dataset item (in the case of an image this is a 3D tensor). The `DataLoader` **collates** multiple outputs from a dataset into a batch, it does this by introducing a new dimension, which gives you 5D output. There are multiple ways to deal with this. One is to override the `DataLoader`'s `collate_fn` parameter with a custom function that collates data in a way you expect.